# How to simulate click on canvas with coordinates?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, click, simulate

In web game I wanted to simulate clicks with coordinates. Game interface using canvas

I tried several things, but nothing help.

I tried to make new MouseEvent but it returns me "true" and nothing happened.

```
const e1 = new MouseEvent("click", {
   clientX: 1673,
   clientY: 866
});

canvas.dispatchEvent(e1)
```

And this returns me error: canvas.elementFromPoint is not a function

`canvas.elementFromPoint(1673,866);`

What im doing wrong or canvas may have another methods to simulate clicks?

Comment: Unable to reproduce. However, note that a real canvas click has the `PointerEvent` type.

Comment: You mean that i have to use PointerEvent instead MouseEvent?

Comment: Perhaps, if the listener responds only to this particular event. In the simplest case it didn't matter.

Comment: What game interface are you trying to manipulate? The goal isn't clear here.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the `.elementFromPoint()` method is to return a HTML element e.g. a `<div>`. As such this method is chained to the [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) object. That means you can't call it on an instance of a canvas element as it simply ain't available there - thus the error message: **canvas.elementFromPoint is not a function**

Here's an example:

```js
const e1 = new MouseEvent("click", {
  clientX: 50,
  clientY: 50
});

const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  console.log(document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY));
});

canvas.dispatchEvent(e1);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hey, your code will not simulate or affect to canvas. For example this game - https://www.thesnidewalk.com/ Lets try to simulate click to button "walk", i tried your code and mine but its not affect to button

Comment: I do not know about your specific circumstances (as those are not part of your question) but you can see that it actually does react to the simulated click simply because the click event listener on the canvas responds to the event and returns the canvas element obtained by document.elementFromPoint. Your button might be a html element which isn't affected by a click on the canvas - so please update your question with a reproducible code sample.

Answer (score 0):

The main game canvas should be inside of an html div that could be clicked.
That main containing div would be what gets resized, and therefore you could add specific divs to it with appendChild and absolute position them for specific buttons on top of the canvas. Or get the specific cords of clicks from the container div.

Answer (score 0):

In my case event was ignored because there was no

```
buttons: 1
```

in event properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
function simulateCanvasClick(x, y) {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const mouseX = x - rect.left;
    const mouseY = y - rect.top;

    const clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
        clientX: mouseX,
        clientY: mouseY
    });

    canvas.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
}
```

simulateCanvasClick(1673, 866);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).